# AngularJS retrieve without specific characters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I want to do a simple `$scope` and get text, but when I do that, I get a string like this:

```
"<p>Hello World</p>"
```

And I want to get only the string without " " to make possible the tags to work with the html like this:

```
<p>Hello World</p>
```

Is there any option to replace that or get it without `" "`?

Edit:

I'm using this to get in my case all of my WordPress posts:

```
$scope.posts = [];
  var wordpressUrl = "mysite";

  $http.get(wordpressUrl)
    .success(function(response){
      console.log("Reveived getPosts via HTTP: ", response, status);
      angular.forEach(response, function(child){
        $scope.posts.push(child);
      });
    })
```

And I'm calling in the `<html>` like this:

```
<h2>{{post.title}}</h2>
<div id="test">
    {{post.content}}
</div>
```

Comment: are you getting it as a string inside controller?

Comment: just edited, may u need more info

Comment: If you want to dynamically render html into your view you need to do this in the `link` method of your directive and use the `$compile` provider.

Comment: Can you please make an example with my code? I'm really new into this and i can't understand you...